# Is it normal for hotels to offer two single beds pushed together when a double bed is booked?

Tags: hotels, terminology

Recently, in multiple hotels, we paid for a double bed but got two smaller beds near each other instead. The two beds can move apart during the night, if you sleep on the middle. Should we complain? Is two twin beds near each other considered a double bed? It feels a little cheap and not correct.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think “double bed” means that the room can accomodate two people sleeping side by side and not much more. The bed is not guaranteed to be as large as you might be used to (especially if you come from North America) and can come in many forms.

In Western/Southern Europe, I would expect only one bed, larger than a single bed but not huge. In some countries in Central Europe, it's really common to have two single beds side by side, with their own separate bed linen or, often, two single mattresses set side by side on a single bed frame. I know people in Germany (married couples) who have that at home. They wouldn't think of that as cheap or surprising in any way. There would however be some way to at least fasten the two beds together, though.

In fact, I have recently stayed at a mid-range German hotel where I got a very nice room, very spacious with all the amenities, a pillow menu, this sort of things. The bed was larger than usual and very comfy… but still came with two separate mattresses and a split between the two people sleeping in it.

International hotel chains might have a more specific terminology but I would not assume that to be universal.

Comment: By definition double bed means "a bed big enough for two people". The two beds are not fastened, so they go apart during the night, which is pretty uncomfortable for a couple. So do I have the right to raise a complain?

Comment: Anyways, I think the key is that this is not specific terminology, so I think I'll accept your answer. Also thanks for everyone who tried to help :-D

Comment: @barotia you can complain, but I'm not sure what you expect it to accomplish.  The hotel's not going to express order different bedding just because you dislike the sort they have.

Comment: @danisfiddlingbyfirelight Probably not, but they might e.g. provide a compensatory dinner.

Comment: Here's a related example of something which perplexes Europeans but is normal in American homes: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120332/why-do-us-hotels-sandwich-the-blanket-between-two-sheets-instead-of-putting-it-i/120344?r=SearchResults#120344

Comment: Two separate mattresses in a single frame, depending on the type of the mattress, can actually be seen as a bonus vs a single big mattress. They help two people not to roll into each other if they don't indend to.

Comment: @barotia Quite apart from the details of what happened, your answer suggests it happened to you at several different locations. That alone suggests that a complain is unlikely to bring much satisfaction.

Comment: I live in Germany and I have a double bed, and it consists in two separate mattresses in a single frame. All double beds I've seen here are of this type (which doesn't mean that *all* of them are like that, but it is rather common). This always surprises foreigners like me but it seems to be pretty much the standard here.

Comment: @DenisNardin, yes, two mattresses in one frame. I, personally, have never seen the "two frame" version, except in hotels, where they (hastily?) pushed together the twin beds of a twin room. - "Doppelbett" will never - reasonably - mean "two beds" in Germany.

Answer (score 10):

I find I find this fairly common.  It makes sense from the hotel's perspective because it allows them to convert a room fairly quickly from one that accommodates two people in one bed to one that accommodates two people in two beds.

I only wish that it were more common to have some sort of latch or other device to hold the beds together in case someone is lying in the middle.

Comment: Bring two pieces if string, spare shoelaces will do, and tie the legs together.

Answer (score 8):

Since you mentioned this is Romania, I found this guide for you.

https://www.esky.ro/ghid-de-calatorie/hoteluri/cazarea-la-hotel/tipuri-de-camere

It says that a double room can have accommodate for 2 people, with 2 beds (joint or separate).

The matrimonial is the one that has the big bed rooms, so it might have been a simple case of lost in translation.

Comment: Just to add for users who do not read Romanian on-line translation seems fine wit the page and it has the major benefit of telling you what to write if you e-mail the hotel.

Comment: Romania, such an interesting country, yes matrimonial, but on a lots of site just says double, no matrimonial option. Btw in the brackets at the matrimonial part also double is mentioned. Anyways thanks for the link.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, checked the hotels page and it states that the rooms for two persons has matrimonial beds.

Answer (score 4):

Hotels normally have a mix of double (rooms with double beds) and twin (rooms with two beds), and will sometimes convert twin rooms into doubles by pushing the beds together.

You can normally ask when checking in if you specifically want a room with a double bed, as they'll normally give you one if they have one available.

Comment: The double/twin distinction is fairly America-specific and not widely used elsewhere.

Comment: The double/twin distinction is crystal clear in British English. That won't stop hotels trying to fob you off with a twin when you booked a double. Still, it's best when booking to explicitly say "A double, not a twin".

Comment: Thanks, next time we'll contact the hotel before booking.